# nmap, splitting range for speed?

Tags: nmap

On a single 8GB machine, Would nmap complete a x.x.x.x/8 scan at the same rate as the x.x.x.x/8 range split into 256 x.x.x.x/16's?

`Adding an additional sentience to get past the "quality standards" error.`

Comment: 8GB what? Assuming RAM. Understand where your limits are coming from: Nmap is network-limited, not memory-limited. Plus, Nmap already splits scans into smaller hostgroups for parallel scanning within each group.

Answer (score 3):

It makes little sense to split the /8 network up unless there's a section of that network that you do not want to be scanned.

As bonsaiviking said nmap is network-limited and splits the network range up to take advantages of its parrallelism features. Nmap is constantly monitoring the performance of the scan to affect the rate at which it sends packets.

To directly control the rate of the scan, use

--min-rate ; --max-rate .